# configuration for different environments with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have reactJS-webpack-grunt app.

I'd like to upload my app to different environments, each with its own settings.
Currently I have one `settings.js` file, and when webpack does its thing (grunt build or serve), the settings gets hidden inside `assets/main.js`.

Currently, in every file that uses settings I've done: `var settings = require('settings');` and in `webpack.config.js` I've declared an alias

```
resolve: {
  root: [
      __dirname,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'main', 'assets')
  ],
  alias: {
      settings: __dirname + "/src/scripts/settings.js"
  },
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
},
```

My intention is to have a different `settings` file, with JSON-like structure, that any non-technical guy could change easily, and to upload my app several times, every time compiling the same code, only `settings.js` stays untouched.

Comment: settings.js stays untouched, but it'll be changed?  I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand, i'll have several servers, in each there will be a copy of the app (and any update will change them all) and a separate settings file. this file won't be deleted when I update the app, and can be changed manually in every server